# Change what is filtered in new Google sheets with Filter view onOpen

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

How can I change (programmatically) the `Filter View` when a *Google SpreadSheet* is opened?

Using the new *Sheets*, I've setup a number of *Filter views* using `Data > Filter view > Create new filter views` based upon usernames in column A.

I would like to have a *Filter view* applied when the SpreadSheet is opened. I would do this via JS in the `onOpen` function.

Based upon active user I would change the *Filter view* - but what *GAS* method is available to do this.  I'm looking for something akin to

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var emailAddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
if (emailAddress == "User1@domain.com" ) {
    sheet.FILTERVIEWMETHOD = "User1"
}     // where "User1" is a Filter View previously defined for this sheet
else if (emailAddress == "User2@domain.com") {
    sheet.FILTERVIEWMETHOD = "User2"
}
```

I'm looking for the `FILTERVIEWMETHOD` to use.

Thanks.

Comment: [issue 524](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=524)